# Python Crontab run a function: OSError: "crontab: user `user' unknown\n"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, cron-task

I want to use task scheduler inside my python script. Here is an example:

```
import datetime
 
def myjob():
    print("%s: This is my present Job"%(datetime.datetime.now()))

from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user='user')
job = cron.new(myjob)
job.minute.every(1)
cron.write()
```

Present output:

```
OSError: Read crontab user: b"crontab: user `user' unknown\n"
```

[image]

**update:** Now I have used user `raspberrypi` but still getting same error.
[image]

Comment: I think 'user' should actually be your username. Eg: 'john'

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki oho! In this case I am running it on Raspberry pi. So, it is the name of the user I am into. Correct? Thanks

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I updated my question. I am still seeing the same error even after updated the user name (I hope it is same as host name).

Comment: If I remember correctly the default user for Raspberry is `pi` if you use Raspbian, but better check if it's still the case since I haven't used raspberries for some years